# Bind DDL when Ddl Selection changed in ASP.NET MVC with jQuery, SQL Server, C#

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to bind a dropdownlist; when the base dropdown is selected from SQL Server with jQuery, my code is like this - I have tried with this code am not ddl selection changed is not firing please help me ....

View:

```
<select id="ddlUnit" name="ddlUnit" class="form-control">
```

Controller :

```
public JsonResult BindDDLUnits(int id)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getado.getConnection());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("S_RunningUnits '" + id + "'");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();

    while(sdr.Read())
    {
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = sdr[0].ToString(), Value = sdr[1].ToString() });
    }

    return Json(li, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

jQuery :

```
$(function () {
  $("#ddlSpecialization").change(function () {
      $.getJSON('/Registration/BindDDLUnits/' + $('#ddlSpecialization').val(), function (data) {
          var items = '<option>Select Unit</option>';
          $.each(data, function (i, unit) {
              items += "<option value='" + unit.Value + "'>" + unit.Text + "</option>";
          });
          $('#ddlUnit').html(items);
      });
  });
});
```